# Can someone explain how the indexing on strings work with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

Given
a = "helloworld"
print(a[0][0][0][0])

When I run this program, it gave me "h" as output. Can someone explain how this works??

Comment: what is unclear?

Comment: What did you think will come?

Comment: The crucial point is that Python does not have a character type. Doing `a[0]` does not return a character, as it would in, say, C. It returns a *string of length 1*. Which you can index into and get *another* string of length 1. This is a consequence of unifying the character and string types, which is one of the things that makes string handling in Python pleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0]` always gets the first character, because it is the first index of the string (or list)

So, if you do `print(a[0])`, it would give the first character 'h'

If you add `[0]` to it, it would give the first character of 'h' which is 'h' itself

So, if you keep adding the `[0]`, it would still give you 'h'

Answer (score 0):

In every languages when it comes to an array it means you are considering a sequence of data's all together of same dataType in a such a manner that the first element is always present at index 0 and the last element is present at the (size of the array provided by the programmer) -1, basically it is a data structure that is used to store values of  homogeneous type.